# Subquery in Linq to Entities in Silverlight

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, silverlight

I want to convert this SQL query to LINQ to Entities in my first Silverlight Project, but I don't know how, I never worked with Linq:

```
select * 
from Tipo t,
Unidad u
where t.Clave = @Clave
and t.Equipo = u.Equipo
and u.IDUni in
(select IDUni
from Orden o
where o.IDUni = u.IDUni
and o.Clave = t.Clave)
```

somebody help me please

Comment: How are you accessing the Entityframework? You can't have an Entity Model inside a Silverlight project

Comment: sorry but I do not quite understand that you're talking about

Comment: for now what I have is:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try this, and both works ok:

```
ObjectSet<Orden> ordenes = this.ObjectContext.Orden;
ObjectSet<Unidad> unidades = this.ObjectContext.Unidad;
ObjectSet<Tipo> tipos = this.ObjectContext.Tipo;

var query = from t in tipos
            from u in unidades
            where t.Clave == _clave
            where t.Equipo == u.Equipo
            where (from o in ordenes
                   where o.IDUni == u.IDUni
                   where o.Clave == t.Clave
                   select o.IDUni).Contains(u.IDUni)
            select new { t, u };
```

and

```
var query = from t in tipos
            from u in unidades
            from o in ordenes
            where t.Clave == _clave
            where t.Equipo == u.Equipo
            where o.IDUni == u.IDUni
            where o.Clave == t.Clave
            select t;
```

thanks so much to

McGarnagle and

Aducci

Answer (score 1):

Here is a translation of your sql query. Are there specific columns you are wanting? It would be unusual to `select *`

```
var query = from t in context.Tipo
            from u in context.Unidad
            where t.Clave == clave
            where t.Equipo == u.Equipo
            where (from o in context.Orden
                   where o.IDUni == u.IDUni
                   where o.Clave == t.Clave
                   select o.IDUni).Contains(u.IDUni)
            select new { t, u };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `Join` followed by a `Where`.  Try something like this:

```
public void DoStuff(IEnumerable<Tipo> t, IEnumerable<Unidad> u, IEnumerable<Orden> o)
{
    string clave = "something";
    var items = t
        .Join(u,                                                 // join to collection "u"
              trow => trow.Equipo,                               // "t" selector
              urow => urow.Equipo,                               // "u" join selector
              (trow, urow) => new { trow = trow, urow = urow })  // result selector
        .Where(item => item.trow.Clave == clave 
                  && o.Where(orow => orow.IDUni == item.urow.IDUni 
                         && orow.Clave == item.trow.Clave)
                     .Select(orow => orow.IDUni)
                     .Contains(item.urow.IDUni)
        );
}
```

Comment: imagine it must be urow => urow.Unidad

Comment: @Cyndy shouldn't be if "Unidad" is the type.  The lambda selects a property "Equipo" of the type "Unidad".

Comment: oooohhh! ok, I understand, is the join between Tipo.Equipo = Unidad.Equipo